# Comprenhension doesn't return the same result as a normal for loop

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

In Python 2.7, I've got some code:

```
values = list()
for i in dict.keys():
    values.append( (i,)+dict[i] )
```

That returns a `values` list which length is 2428.

The same, but with comprehension mode returns a list of length -> 1, each 2428 elements are nested 1 level deeper (`len(values[0])` -> 2428):

```
values = list()
values.append( (i,)+dict[i] for i in dict.keys() )
```

I simply wonder why. I must miss something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just appended a generator expression - a single object - to your list.

You can either `extend` the list with the gen. exp. which is an iterable:

```
values = list()
values.extend( (i,)+dct[i] for i in dct )
```

Or use a *list comprehension* to build your list which is the more standard way:

```
values = [(k,)+v for k, v in dct.items()]
```

Notice that I've used the `items` method of the dict to generate key-value pairs at a go, that `.keys` can be dropped when you're iterating on the dict and that `dict` is not a good name since it shadows the built-in `dict`.

You can read more about [Generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: Idea is good but this is messing up the keys and the related values; keys seem to be sorted and values not. I absolutely need them to be pairwised as values are items for features and keys are the features' IDs.

Comment: @s.k: You have some other bug, then.